# Wealth disparity between the voters and the rulers in democracies

Tags: democracy, inequality

Are there any studies looking at the disparity between the wealth of the electorate and the wealth of the rulers?

I don't think that anyone would argue with the suggestion that by-and-large, the rulers are wealthier than the ruled (even in countries with genuinely free and fair elections)

I'm interested in both why this happens, why would a country with a predominately poor electorate vote willingly (apparently) for rulers who are much better of and probably don't actually have much in common with them, and I'm also interested in which democratic countries is this most prevalent. My gut feeling is the answer is the USA but I'd like to try to understand why.

Comment: I suspect that most "rulers" are paid significantly more than the national average, so sort of by definition once you become a ruler, you are no longer "in common" with the electorate, at least economically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that elected officials are more affluent than their constituents all around the world.  [This article](http://people.duke.edu/%7Enwc8/voterbiases.pdf) explains that:

1. elected officials are almost always wealthier, more educated, and more likely to come from white-collar jobs than the citizens who elect them
2. Across Latin American democracies, workers make up between 60 and 90 percent of the general public, but legislators from those occupations make up just 5 to 25 percent of national legislatures
3. In Europe, blue-collar workers make up large proportions of the electorate but
   have rarely made up more than 10 percent of national legislatures

Interestingly, the study they conducted showed that the voters they surveyed in the US, UK and Argentina, would be just as likely to vote for a factory worker as they would be to vote for a business owner.  The study did not investigate how well the working class was represented in candidacy for office or offer other explanations for why fewer working class individuals are not in public office.  I would suggest two likely reasons.

**Funding:**

One clear challenge for an average working-class individual who wishes to pursue politics is how to afford it.  In order to receive votes, one must be known and supported by a large percentage of potential voters.  Self-promotion is not free and it takes time.  For an individual with a full-time job, who can't afford a personal assistant, a maid, a nanny, and so forth, it is difficult to compete with other candidates that have more significant resources and fewer time constraints.  Wealthier people also tend to have more wealthy friends, so if they want to raise funds, they don't have to talk to as many friends as a poor person does to raise the same amount of money.

In the US, there is a very strong correlation between fundraising and winning, outlined in [this 538 piece](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/money-and-elections-a-complicated-love-story/).  Knowing more people with money and having money to hire a staff gives wealthy candidates an enormous advantage.  They can more easily run for a more significant office and compete on the fundraising front, thus increasing their chances of winning the first time out.  Some wealthy or well-known individuals have been able to jump straight into a governor or senator role.  Rules about fundraising and spending vary widely by country, so money affects each region differently, but it likely plays a role everywhere.

Middle-class candidates can still run for public office, may have to start smaller, like a city or community position and then build a network of contacts and try to work up to larger offices.  Sometimes, a paid government position can lead to an opportunity to run for office.  This may means that it takes much longer for a working class individual to rise through the ranks in politics and run for more prominent positions.

**Inclination:**

There is also the simple question of interest.  If an individual is a very skilled mechanic, are they as likely to want to hold public office as a CEO of a large corporation, for example?  A mechanic may have excellent problem solving skills that could be beneficial in public office, but may not have any interest in performing the duties of said office.  They may prefer a jumpsuit to a business suit and a garage to an office.  A CEO, on the other hand, already wears a business suit and works in an office.  It's possible that fewer working class people want to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There is the hope that rulers especially in a democracy are *not* average people. How much of a wealth loss should a professional like a lawyer, an engineer, a physician suffer after being elected?

- Representatives in the German Bundestag receive a "salary" of [€10k/month](https://www.bundestag.de/services/glossar/glossar/D/diaeten-245378) and an expenses allowance of €5k/month. That's four times the average [salary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_countries_by_average_wage).
- Average wealth is more problematic to evaluate, but there are news reports that it might be around €60k. With somewhat frugal living, a single term in parliament should allow a representative to save enough to exceed this sum.

Comment: Median income in Germany is around 1.5k€/month; >40% of all households own less than 8k€.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, the difference between *average* and *median* and between *individual* and *family* wealth makes a difference, but not significantly for the answer I'm giving. The income for a member of parliament is several times higher than average, but not in the same ballpark as a top sports star or top lawyer or top manager.